# "Could not change to the Templates directory()..." Error in Dev C++

Tags: dev-c++

I am using [Dev C++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dev-C%2B%2B) for programming, and I can create a new file, but not a project. If I try to create a project then this error occurs:

> Could not change to the Templates Directory().."

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

A problem like this sometimes is solved in the easiest way by just not solving it at all. Try to update Dev-C++ and then restart it and see if that works. If it doesn't, then uninstall it and download it directly from Blookshed.net or SourceForge, then reinstall it.